# Should I use a vapor barrier when repairing a portion of the wall?

Tags: drywall, vapor-barrier

I'm replacing sheetrock 2.5' up from subfloor in remedy to mold issue.

Does it make sense/provide benefit to put up a vapor barrier for this portion of the wall?
The sheetrock that remains is foil-backed, if that matters.

Comment: First question - what caused the mold issue in the first place?

Comment: Well, hard to say for sure.  We've been in the house for two years, with no moisture issues, though we did replace the roof right after moving in.

Comment: Was the mold on the interior or exterior side of the dry wall?  If it was on the interior side, how did you discover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really interesting question.  Given that you are only doing some of the wall I would say NO.

First I could see the point of doing it.  You put up a vapor barrier and if water gets in the wall it leaves via condensation and doesn't hit the back of the drywall.  Given that you have proper airflow in the wall cavity.  This would certainly be a pro.

The con is that if you get water from above and it trickles down, it will get trapped between the vapor barrier and drywall.  This would cause issues with even a small amount of moisture.  So here I think the con wins.  Also if I have moisture in my walls I would rather just see it faster, not become a bigger issue.  Replacing 2.5 feet of drywall is the optimal issue to have right?